# 68HC05 assembly - 't' after integer literal

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, motorola

I'm in the middle of rewriting some assembly code written for a 68HC05 Motorola/Freescale series microcontroller. My goal is to rewrite the assembly code as C so that I can attempt to recreate the project with an Atmel AVR.

I've noticed throughout some of the code that some integer literals are followed by a 't', as seen by this example instruction:

```
cmp #12t
```

I have been unable to find any mentions of `t` in any documentation.

My question is: what is the meaning of `t`, or does it not have one?

Comment: `t` usually means base ten (decimal), `h` is hexadecimal, `q` or `o` is octal and `b` for binary. The syntax differs among assemblers.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, thank you. That does indeed seem likely the case, although it's a bit odd that the author of this code hasn't used `t` for every base ten integer.